# Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1) and Invalid character in name at (1)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to compile the following code with extension .f90 in gfortran:

```
g8(x,h) = h * ( ( & 
          w1 * ( func ( x - x1 * h,ybar,jpr,mu,sigmam,sigmae,rhom,N ) + func ( x + x1 * h,ybar,jpr,mu,sigmam,sigmae,rhom,N ) )   &
        + w2 * ( func ( x - x2 * h,ybar,jpr,mu,sigmam,sigmae,rhom,N ) + func ( x + x2 * h,ybar,jpr,mu,sigmam,sigmae,rhom,N ) ) ) &
      + ( w3 * ( func ( x - x3 * h,ybar,jpr,mu,sigmam,sigmae,rhom,N ) + func ( x + x3 * h,ybar,jpr,mu,sigmam,sigmae,rhom,N ) )   &
        + w4 * ( func ( x - x4 * h,ybar,jpr,mu,sigmam,sigmae,rhom,N ) + func ( x + x4 * h,ybar,jpr,mu,sigmam,sigmae,rhom,N ) ) ) )
```

and get the following errors.

```
procedures.f90:493.130:

am,sigmae,rhom,N ) + func ( x + x1 * h,ybar,jpr,mu,sigmam,sigmae,rhom,N ) )  
                                                                       1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)
procedures.f90:494.13:

        + w2 * ( func ( x - x2 * h,ybar,jpr,mu,sigmam,sigmae,rhom,N ) + fun
         1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

Anyone with an idea?

Comment: lines too long?

Comment: The lines in your example are 131 characters long. Any indentation and you are too long. Btw `g8(x,h)` is also suspicious, are you using `real` variables to index an array?

Comment: Thanks, it works now after decreasing the number of characters in a line.